# Why should i use a Toolkit to implemement MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, toolkit

Today i was doing a POC using MVVM Light Toolkit.

My Senoir asked why do we have to use MVVM light toolkit. He said we have to explain it to client that why do we want to use it.

I tried to suggest things like Built in classes for Commands ,Messages but i dont thinks it was strong enough.

What are the Pros and Cons of using this. Is it not good or its not flexible enough...

I would really appreciate of your help on this.... i know that application can be built without it as well so why to use a framework???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the same kind of question was asked few minutes ago

[Custom MVVM implementation Vs. PRISM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251821/custom-mvvm-implementation-vs-prism)

Please, try to search just a bit before posting this kind of questions ;)

Answer (score 3):

Money, money, money. Time is money. If you save time with toolkits that are free(or not free, but you can save the time to write them) you save money.