# How to avoid setting field values directly so to always trigger a setter, and PropertyChanged notifications

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I have a property setter which triggers notification. But the C# compiler does not know/complain anything if I just use the field, and directly assign values. But if I do that property changed notification is completely useless. I am seeing this mistake being made quite often. SO my questions are

1. How to verify if this mistake (setting filed value instead of using setter) is made in a large solution,
2. How to force some kind of warning or errors when this happens

Since no question is complete without a code sample, here is the illustration of proplem

```
class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private string personName;
        public string PersonName
        {
            get { return personName; }
            set { if(personName!=value)
                  {
                        personName = value;
                        this.OnPropertyChanged ("PersonName");
                  }
                }
        }
        public bool dummy()
        {
            personName = "not notified"; //need to detect/avoid this
        }
}
```

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged itself state that what it can do. you are assigning value directly to a member variable not to the property.

Comment: Some avoid this recommendation like plague, but it does really help if you start your field names with an `underscore`, making your life a little easier.

Comment: You can't do this via `INotifyPropertyChanged` because the Property did not change. This is the kind of thing that you should catch in code reviews :)

Comment: Yeah, I am finding them in code reviews, but since we are one of the groups that Mathew referred, its hard to catch them. I think its time to change I guess.

Comment: If the fact that change notification does not work when the code is tested and a code review is not enough for you then naming conventions (underscores) may help. I would enforce discipline rather than look at any kind of 'coded' solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try an extension.

[Kind Of Magic](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d5cd6aa1-57a5-4aaa-a2be-969c6db7f88a) automatically adds at compile time the necessary "raisers" for you. So you can use  only [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) and avoid the private field.

It works like this:

Instead of write all code:

```
public string Name  
{ 
  get  
  {  
    return _name;  
  } 
  set  
  {  
    if (_name != value) 
    { 
      _name = value; 
      RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Just use an attribute to do this work:

```
[Magic] 
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The extension have much more option. I think you should take a look.

**Edit**
If you search more you can find even more extension that try avoid type all the pattern of `INotifyPropertyChanged` without lose functionality.

Comment: Awesome, I think that addin solves lots of my problem. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK. In this application properties are only **WPF UI gateway**. Use a following naming convention to recognize properties and fields simpler:

```
//Camel convention and beginning with underscore and small letter
private String _personName; 

//Camel convention and capital letter beginning
public string PersonName { get; set; }
```

By normal, in `ViewModel` properties do not have to be accessed: it is **commands'** prerogative. All you have to do in `ViewModel` is to initialize private fields in constructor.

That **is not kind of potential error** to raise up a warning, but it may be a first step to obfuscate code a much.

Of course if you are so worried about breaking MVVM pattern principles, there is a range of frameworks which cope with MVVM routine successfully.

Also you can find it useful to [refresh MVVM knowledge with some guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273357/what-is-prism-for-wpf).