# Silverlight MVVM framework

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, frameworks

Just out of curiosity, wanted to know if there is a need to use any MVVM frame work available as third party installable or we can directly create and define different projects in our application and call them as Model, ViewModel and View, and also use them as per their definition.

Does the third party framework provide anything extra and can a application as mentioned in the above paragraph can be called as MVVM compliant.

Comment: You don't need a 3rd party framework to develop in the MVVM style, but they do offer utility APIs. I use MVVM Light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to use any third party framework, you can just follow the design pattern. You can follow this link to find out more.

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/the-mvvm-pattern/using-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an MVVM framework then I would suggest [Catel](http://catel.codeplex.com/)

The approach which you're thinking of is not what I personally would call 'MVVM compliant' (altough it is only a pattern). Normally your Models are classes to describe and access your data (Linq2Sql entities), ViewModel are classes which drive the applications business logic and your Views are just windows/pages etc. 
Normally I just create folders in my main project for all three of them and take it from there but sometimes it is a good idea to get the Models into a separate project if they are going to be used by other ones but I would normally call it something like `MyProjectData`

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary to use any of the available MVVM frameworks, you can create your own MVVM framework and use it. If you folllow the guidelines for MVVM patern and implement the framework correctly then the application would be MVVM compliant.

But yes MVVM frameworks have there advantages, they provide a lot of features/base classes out of the box which you will have to implement yourself in your custom MVVM implementation; for e.g. Prism provides a standard way of solving various problems/scenarios encountered in SL or WPF application (EventAggregator, Navigation framework, commanding etc.).

Have a look at this question which I had asked about Prism -

[Custom MVVM implementation Vs. PRISM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251821/custom-mvvm-implementation-vs-prism)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use third party framework for it. You just need to follow the architecture of MVVM and try to implement your code in that. Your can learn more about MVVM here [enter link description here](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/30/silverlight-4-mvvm-with-commanding-and-wcf-ria-services.aspx)

[Best for MVVM Architecture](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/30/silverlight-4-mvvm-with-commanding-and-wcf-ria-services.aspx)